# Expo Web ( React Native for Web) not showing console.log

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web, expo-web

I am quite new to Expo and am trying to turn my React Native App into an additional web app. I’m pretty excited about Expo Web / React Native Web, but unfortunately I have the problem that I don’t see any outputs in the Expo Dev Tool (where the webpack is started), nor in the command line outputs of console.log. Is there a trick for this?

If i do a Alert("...") instead of a console.log it works. But this is not so good to work with fetch.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In the Developer Tools there should be 2 windows 1 from device and 1 is the metro Bundler if you started the app check top right corner to enable the second view maybe.

Comment: I have the same issue.